# How do I include variable between {} brackets in a php preg_match?

Tags: php, variables, preg-match

So I currently have this php code

```
preg_match('/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,**3**}/', $text, $abstract);
```

Instead of the number 3 I would like it to be a variable example >

```
preg_match('/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,**$variable**}/', $text, $abstract);
```

Please help thanks a lot :)

Comment: How would you normally put a variable into a string? And that's your answer.

Comment: Another small question by any chance do you guys know how to get the content remaining after that preg_match is done ?? Since that preg match gets the amount of sentences as set by $variable... Now I want to make a different preg_match which will get the remaining text after the first three sentences ?? Thanks a lot

Comment: Put a capture group with `(.*)` after the regexp. `$abstract[2]` will then contain the rest of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes, and the variable will be substituted:

```
preg_match("/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,$variable}/", $text, $abstract);
```

Comment: This works @Barmar Thanks a lot .... I cannot tick as correct or give rating as I am not experienced yet by stack overflow sorry but the answer is this

Comment: Green button checked ;) ... Another small question by any chance do you guys know how to get the content remaining after that preg_match is done ?? Since that preg match gets the amount of sentences as set by $variable... Now I want to make a different preg_match which will get the remaining text after the first three sentences ?? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem was fixed using php concatenation like when joining a string.... The problem when I tried this previously was that I was using + instead of . like other languages.

the code is now as follows

```
preg_match('/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,' . $var . '}/', $text, $abstract);
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, stuff between `'` quotes are taken literally. so `'$myVar'` isn't the value of `$myVar`, it's literally the string `"$myVar"`.

If you want a variable, you can concat the strings like `'/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,' . $variable . '}/'`

In other cases (not regexes) you can use `"` quotes instead.

edit; PHP string concat is `.`, not `+`  good job, self >_>

Comment: unfortunately concatenation is not working for me over here :(

Comment: Concatenation is `.` in PHP, not `+`.

Comment: riiight - string concat is `.` - haven't used PHP in a while, my bad